# What's an example of a situation in which it makes sense to assume random slopes but a fixed intercept?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, mixed-model

I'm referring to multilevel modelling. Field (2013) writes:

> It’s worth noting that it would be unusual in reality to assume random
>   slopes without also assuming random intercepts, because variability in
>   the nature of the relationship (slopes) would normally create
>   variability in the overall level of the outcome variable (intercepts).
>   Therefore, if you assume that slopes are random you would normally
>   also assume that intercepts are random.

Can anyone think of an example (preferably, but not necessarily, from an actual analysis) in which it was appropriate to assume random slopes but a fixed intercept? Why was it appropriate in that case?

Field, Andy. Discovering statistics using IBM SPSS statistics. Sage, 2013.

Comment: What is Field (2014)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the citation in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have random slopes in your model, then your random intercept is a function of how your variables that enter the model with the random slopes are centered. See page 54 of the [GLVM book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584880007) ("search inside" for "cluster-specific regression lines")... which is arguably a better source of information regarding multilevel models than the undergraduate book you refer to.

You may have some exceptional situations when the center or the zero of that variable has a very strong meaning for the model, e.g., when you have a growth that must start from zero (e.g., if a farm has no land, it cannot produce any crop). Otherwise, I would say that the model without the random intercept is weird at the very least, and most likely is not making sense.

Answer (score 0):

The intercept variance and the intercept-slope covariance depend on the x variable origin, so that information should be generated from the data. If you fix the intercepts, then the relationships between the factors at x=0 might make sense for one factor, but not wrt its relationship with any other factors.